# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting error

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

for the below query not sure where I went wrong, but I am getting output if I ignore top 10 from the query

```
create procedure sp_dynamicsql
(
    @year nvarchar(max) 
    
)
as
begin 
    declare @num int
    declare @rc nvarchar(5)
    declare @sqlstring nvarchar(max)
    set @num=10
    set @rc = cast(@num as nvarchar(5))
    

    set @sqlstring =
    N'select top'+ @rc +' * from tblfilm 
    where year(FilmReleaseDate)='+ @year +
    N'order by FilmReleaseDate'

    exec sp_executesql @sqlstring
end
```

when I exec the above query it got "Commands completed successfully."

but when I exec

```
exec [dbo].[sp_dynamicsql] '2000'
```

I get error stating
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: `N'select top'+ @rc +` - you are missing one space there, it is a typo.

Comment: inside your procedure you can always add print(@sqlstring) to see the formed string. @year nvarchar(max)  looks nice, but year usually is smallint or integer

Comment: *If* you're going to use string concatenation to construct queries (you really ought not to, most of the time), the first thing to learn is to *print out the complete result* and include that in your question if you cannot spot the issue yourself. The prime mistake is assuming you know what the final string will look like and not verifying that.

Comment: There is nothing in that query that requires Dynamic SQL.    For example Select top (@rc) ...

Comment: You need a space before the keyword `TOP`, should use a parameterized query, use an appropriate type for @year (1GB is excessive), and refactor the WHERE clause to use indexes efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer because the above is just dangerous, end of story. You have defined `@Year` as a `nvarchar(MAX)`, so you are stating that the value of your parameter is likely to be 4,000 or more characters in length, and *could be* up to ~1 billion characters in length. A year made up of 4,000 characters would be enough time for us to reach the heat death of the universe around *37 times* (from the current date)... There is no reason to require a year *that* long.

There is, in truth, no need for a dynamic statement here; both `TOP` and your `WHERE` can be parametrised:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.undynamicsql @year int --Don't use the sp_ prefix, it's reserved by Microsoft for System/Special procedures
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @num int = 10;

    SELECT TOP (@num)
           * --Replace this with an explicit list of columns
    FROM dbo.tblfilm
    WHERE FilmReleaseDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@year, 1, 1) --Use a date range, it's SARGable
      AND FilmReleaseDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@year + 1, 1, 1)
    ORDER BY FilmReleaseDate;

END;
```

If you *must* use a deferred statement, at least parametrise the statement properly:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.defferedsql @year int 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @num int = 10;
    
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF char(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP (@num)' + @CRLF +
               N'       * --Replace this with an explicit list of columns' + @CRLF +
               N'FROM dbo.tblfilm' + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE FilmReleaseDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@year, 1, 1)' + @CRLF +
               N'  AND FilmReleaseDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@year + 1, 1, 1)' + @CRLF +
               N'ORDER BY FilmReleaseDate;';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@num int, @Year int', @num, @year;

END;
```

Comment: Good and helpful answer, but maybe you should mention OP's real issue anyway(missing space after `top` in `top'+ @rc +`)

Comment: The comments handle that in all honestly, @TimSchmelter , and it's typographical at "best". The *real* problem, in my opinion, stems from the fact the OP is using dynamic SQL in the first place.

Comment: Thanks all got sorted it was the space problem as most of you told thanks :)

Comment: @ThomA Thanks for your inputs, it is helpful.
yes learning dynamic SQL for first time